# How to use preg_replace on a URL

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

How do I use `preg_replace` text/url. For example, I have a url like this: `http://www.web.org/dorama/1201102144/hitoya-no-toge`. I just want to show `web.org`. The url is not always same, for example sometimes it's: `http://www.web.org/movies/123/no` etc.

I only know the basics of it. Here is what I tried.  It still does not delete the `slash`.

```
$url = "http://www.web.org/dorama/1201102144/hitoya-no-toge";
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/http:/';
$patterns[1] = '/dorama/';
$patterns[2] = '/1201102144/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = '';
$replacements[1] = '';
$replacements[0] = '';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $url);
```

result when i run it `//www.web.org///hitoya-no-toge`

Comment: Are you asking how to simply extract the domain (`www.web.org`), or how to replace the domain `www.web.org` with `www.piratefiles.org` when there's an **unknown** number of subfolders? For the latter, you'd first want to extract the domain and then simply append the final segment.

Comment: ah, my bad. im already fix it using `preg_match`

Answer (score 1):

For such a job, I'd use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) then [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$url = "http://www.web.org/dorama/1201102144/hitoya-no-toge";
$host = (parse_url($url))['host'];
$domain = (explode('.', $host, 2))[1];
echo $domain;
```

**Output:**

```
web.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` instead `preg_replace` i think http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
// get host name from URL
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $url, $matches);
$host = $matches[1];

// get last two segments of host name
preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
echo "{$matches[0]}"
```

If use https change http to https, I don't know how to make it work for http and https.